# Characteristics of a smooth belt

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, mechanical

I want to replace a cylindrical pulley, so I came across a component called a smooth belt.
[image]

Now this thing came with many differenent variations, from `2.00"` up to `8.00"`.
Since I don't know which one to get, what is this varying parameter? What does this value imply?

Also, the `1/4"` refers to the diameter of the cylinder of the plastic, is that correct?

**EDIT:** The picture here is just a picture I found in an online store. I measured the parameters of mine that I want to replace.
The thickness of the plastic is `1.5mm` (this means `1/16` of an inch) and the diameter of the circle is `4.5cm`.

Comment: If that picture is to scale, I can see that the radius is 8 times the diameter: 2"

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a link to the manufacturer? You are correct about the quarter inch (gauge). If I were to guess the varying value is the length of the belt measured as internal diameter. Also remember force is equal to K*dx, so the more stretch on the belt the larger the force.

Comment: I edited the question with the specific measurements of the one that I am looking for. No, i don't know manufacturer. I just want to find a replacement.